# How to make some icons at Appbar with different alignment?

Tags: flutter, android-appbarlayout, flutter-appbar

I faced some problem. I want make an image, a text and two icons in `AppBar` but I can't make it work as I want.

[image]

I tried to make some fonts in a row after the images and text. The images and the text successful show in my `AppBar`, but the rest of 2 fonts (Trolley and notifications) show some error.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,  
      appBar: new AppBar
        (
        title: new Row
          (
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children:
            [
              Image.asset('images/logoapp.png',fit: BoxFit.contain,height: 32,), 
              Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: Text('Solid Shop'))
            ],
          )

        ),
```

....

Comment: You can combine with spacers.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use `leading` to set a widget before appBar title & use `actions` to specify list of widgets in appBar which appears on right side of appBar title.

```
AppBar(
    leading: Image.asset('yourImage'), // you can put Icon as well, it accepts any widget.
    title: Text ("Your Title"),
    actions: [
        Icon(Icons.add),
        Icon(Icons.add),
    ],
);
```

Read more about it [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)

Answer (score 13):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Solid Shop"),
      leading: Image.asset("your_image_asset"),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart), onPressed: () {}),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.message), onPressed: () {}),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `actions` instead of `title`

```
actions: <Widget>[
          Image.asset('images/logoapp.png',fit: BoxFit.contain,height: 32,), 
              Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: Text('Solid Shop')),

          Image.asset('images/logoapp.png',fit: BoxFit.contain,height: 32,), // here add notification icon
              Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: Text('Solid Shop')) // here add other icon
        ],
```

Comment: thank you so much mr @Taym for your answer.

I've try your suggestion and it works for me.
but there is something little wrong was happened.
maybe its caused by too big images i put them.. it looks not too good. but I'll try how to make it looks good :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add icon and also a picture on app bar, this code works for me:-

appBar: AppBar(

```
    centerTitle: true,

    elevation: 2,

    title: Center(

      child: Row(

        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

        children: [

          Image.asset(

            "assets/images/bell.png",

            fit: BoxFit.contain,

            height: 28,

          ),

          Container(

            child: Text("  APP BAR"),

          )

        ],

      ),

    ),

    actions: [

      IconButton(

        icon: Icon(Icons.settings),

        onPressed: () {

          Navigator.push(

            context,

            MaterialPageRoute(

              builder: (context) {

                return Settings();

              },

            ),

          );

        },

        color: Colors.white,
      )

    ],

  ),
```

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine it with Spacers :

```
 actions: const [
                Spacer(flex: 3),
                Icon(Icons.fit_screen),
                Spacer(flex: 10),
                Icon(Icons.width_normal),
                Spacer(flex: 1),
                Icon(Icons.aspect_ratio),
                Spacer(flex: 1),
                Icon(Icons.ad_units),
                Spacer(flex: 5),
              ],
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
appBar: AppBar(
    leading: Image.asset("assets/print.png"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    actions: const [
      Icon(Icons.ac_unit_outlined),
      Icon(Icons.ac_unit_outlined),
    ],
    title: const Center(child: Text('Page Three')),
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?